# TypeError for every array of objects after index 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, react-leaflet

Working with react leaflet and a water api. I create an array of objects from the data obtained from the API, console log shows I have all the correct data, particularly at line 109 it does output the correct information. Yet, on lines 254 and 255, using    `obj2[1]`
just gives me 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.' Switching the index at those two lines back to 0 makes it compiles and run, but that's obviously not the right data. What is going on here?

```
 let obj2 =[{}];
  if(water){
    console.log(water);
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        obj2[i] ={
            name: water.value.timeSeries[i].sourceInfo.siteName,
            site: water.value.timeSeries[i].sourceInfo.siteCode[0].value,
            lat:  water.value.timeSeries[i].sourceInfo.geoLocation.geogLocation.latitude,
            long: water.value.timeSeries[i].sourceInfo.geoLocation.geogLocation.longitude,
            temp: water.value.timeSeries[i].values[0].value[0].value
        };
    }
    console.log(obj2);
    PRA = [obj2[0].lat, obj2[0].long]; //PUDDING RIVER AT AURORA
    TRL = [obj2[1].lat, obj2[1].long]; //TUALITIN RIVER NEAR WEST LINN
    CSC = [obj2[2].lat, obj2[2].long]; //CRYSTAL SPRINGS CREEK
    WRP = [obj2[3].lat, obj2[3].long]; //WILLAMETTE RIVER AT PORTLAND
    BCB = [obj2[4].lat, obj2[4].long]; //BEVERTON CREEK AT BEAVERTO
    console.log(obj2[0].name)
    console.log(obj2[1].name)
  }
```

console shows

```
Page.js:108 PUDDING RIVER AT AURORA, OR
Page.js:109 TUALATIN RIVER AT OSWEGO DAM, NEAR WEST LINN, OR
```

Error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
Page
/src/Page.js:266

```
  263 | radius={900}
  264 | >
  265 |     <Popup>
> 266 |     <div><b>{obj2[1].name}</b></div>
      | ^  267 |     <div>Temp: {obj2[1].temp} C</div>
  268 |     </Popup>
  269 | </Circle>
```

Leaflet portion I'm working on. Changing the index back to 0 fixes it.

```
   <Marker position={TRL} icon={mapMarker}>
                        <Circle
                        color={'purple'}
                        center={TRL}
                        radius={900}
                        >
                            <Popup>
                            <div><b>{obj2[1].name}</b></div>
                            <div>Temp: {obj2[1].temp} C</div>
                            </Popup>
                        </Circle>
                    </Marker>
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you make the API call and this process takes time to get data from the server so the first time the obj2 is empty so when you call obj2[1].name is throwing error

**The solution is to do this**

```
  <div> {obj2.length > 1 && obj2[2].name}</div>
 <div> {obj2.length > 1 && obj2[2].temp}</div>
```

Comment: obj2[0].name works fine, so can it be an issue with the time to process the data? This solution did not work, by the way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the issue is with the time to process the data

Comment: please try this solution obj2[2] !== undifined && obj2[1].name